# iOS app stacks on login when permission removed through web interface

Tags: ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an issue with iOS6 which is app can't re-authenticate after its permission was removed through web interface

Its state stays "On" in iOS preferences, which does not reflect current state of OAuth

Which leads to limbo when app tries to authenticate but gets an OAuth error

Also seems like there is no way to manually remove permission from builtin facebook preferences

Did anyone face similar issues? Any possible workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

If the Facebook access token in the iOS cache is out of sync with Facebook, you can force a sync of the credentials:

```
// Only do this if there is native Facebook Account support (iOS 6+)
BOOL isFacebookAccountsAvailable = (&ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook != NULL);
if (isFacebookAccountsAvailable) {
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [ACAccountStore new];
    ACAccountType *accountTypeFB = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    NSArray *fbAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountTypeFB];

    for (ACAccount *fbAccount in fbAccounts)
        [accountStore renewCredentialsForAccount:fbAccount completion:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult renewResult, NSError *error) {
            DLog(@"Renew account error: %@", error.localizedDescription)
        }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having pretty much the same issue. I tried to remove my app from my applications list on the Facebook website. Now when I log out and log back in, I get the same invalid token. I've got to go to the settings on my iPhone and disable facebook access for my app. This resets the token.

The SDK provides a method

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

but it does not solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the case is being handled correctly with latest update of Facebook SDK